# Error in opening file having ambersand in the name in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have problem in opening file with ambersand in between.

```
var attachment = "attachment;" + "&test& incident&.txt";

 HtmlPage.Window.CreateInstance("foo2", new object[] { Id.ToString(), attachment });


function foo2(theAlert, type) {
            alert(type);
            window.open('fileViewer.aspx?Id=' + theAlert + '&Type=' + type);

        }
```

When i try to get the type in another page i am getting only the "attachment;" because it taking the words before ampersand. and missing my filename. If i give file name without ampersand i dont have any problem in opening the file.

Any one help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is because the ampersand is like a reserved character in terms of URLs.

Comment: ya, but for my scenario i have to use. can you help me how to solve the problem.

Comment: try with `attachment = attachment HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(attachment )`

Comment: its returning attachmentTFS%3b not the entire file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`encodeURIComponent`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp)

> The encodeURIComponent() function encodes a URI component.
>
> This function encodes special characters. In addition, it encodes the
>
> following characters: , / ? : @ & = + $ #

```
window.open('fileViewer.aspx?Id=' + theAlert + '&Type=' + encodeURIComponent(type));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
window.open("fileViewer.aspx?Id=" + theAlert + "&Type=" + encodeURIComponent(type));
```

Changed from encodeURI to encodeURIComponent:

- encodeURI is intended for use on the full URI.
- encodeURIComponent is intended to be used on .. well .. URI components that is any part that lies between separators (; / ? : @ & = + $ , #).

Comment: thanks a lot, i tried with uri it didnt work. with urimcomponent its working fine.thanks for your time to share this info